# MacBook reboots during a long sleep if FileVault is turned on

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, filevault

I've turned on **FileVault** on my MacBook Pro 2018 (High Sierra) and immediately after this the MacBook started to reboot randomly (mostly) when in sleep.

First I noticed that after putting my Mac into sleep I need to enter a password to unlock it (touch ID disabled) and that all my applications are closed. Looks like a reboot...

Then once when waking up my computer from sleep I got this message ***"Terminal interrupted logout. To continue logout, quit Terminal"***. This convinced me that the MacBook is trying to reboot itself during sleep.

It never happened before - but happens during all long sleep cycles (no matter if during the day or night) since **FileVault** is turned on.

Any ideas how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Wanted to add: before turning FileVault on, I have normally had Terminal running for days/weeks with a "ping 192.168.1.1" command so I am 100% sure that my mac was able to sleep/wake/sleep/wake with applications like Terminal running.

Comment: Discovered that the "Terminal interrupted logout" was a false alarm because it was caused by "System Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> Advanced -> Log out after 60 minutes of inactivity" setting being turned on. However rebooting during sleep still happens :(

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem and found this Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> "Firewall" -> Advanced -> Log out after 60 minutes of inactivity" setting being turned on too!.

I believe you forgot the  -> "Firewall" -> route in your description!

Thanks this was the solution for me!